# how to check the null before splitting string

Tags: c#, string, split

I am new to c# programming. Could someone please help me find out how to check whether the string is null before splitting it. I used the below method, but it throws a null reference error if the string is null.

```
string[] splittedString=orgString.Split(',');
```

Comment: What is missing in your question, is what you want to do when the string is null.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
string cleanedString = orgString ?? "";
string[] splittedString = cleanedString.Split(',');
```

Comment: +1 for the best approach

Comment: I don't like this answer. This will hide the null string. Most of cases, if the string is null, there's probably a problem earlier in the code. Either an unchecked nullity at the beginning of the method,

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using [String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.isnullorwhitespace.aspx) as this will not only check if the string is null, but also make sure that it isn't empty.

```
string orgString = null;

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(orgString))
{
    string[] splittedString = orgString.Split(',');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String.IsNullOrEmpty(string)
```

or just for null

```
if (string == null)
```

Comment: There is no `===` operator in c#

Comment: Ha ya, sorry, bad (good) habits...